# Graphics dim, but mouse cursor not dim

Tags: xorg, monitors, suspend, multi-monitor

When I resume from suspend-to-ram often the graphics on my internal screen is dim (around 30-50% intensity). Initially I thought it might be the backlight, but the mouse cursor is not dimmed - only everything else.

I also tried:

```
xbacklight -set 100
xbacklight -set 50
```

There is no change in the intensity of neither in the graphics nor the cursor.

A switch to another virtual terminal (CTRL-ALT-F2) and back (CTRL-ALT-F7) also did not change anything.

I attached an external screen and took a screen shot spanning both screens. The screen shot shows everything at full intensity.

`xpdyinfo` sees the two spanning screens as a single screen - thus does not treat the internal screen different.

Logging out and logging in again solves the issue, so it is clearly a software issue. The re-login seems to restart Xorg, but I would like to not have to re-login just to get the graphics on my screen un-dimmed.

```
Hardware: HP EliteBook 8540w
Software Ubuntu 11.10.
Window manager: xfce
```

How can I un-dim the graphics?

Comment: Do you have a tool that changes the gamma and/or other colour parameters for your internal screen? If it's an nVidia chip, there's `nvidia-settings`, but `xgamma` should work regardless. That *may* reset the CLUT on your card.

Comment: I tested xgamma: It only affects the external monitor when using -d :0. -d :1 does not work. Also if I try the darkest setting (-gamma 0.1) text written in white is not dimmed. Good guess, though. Xorg indicates it is a Radeon card.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue on a Radeon card.  Fixed it when it happened by tweaking the gamma setting in Catalyst Control Center.  Worth a shot if you're able to install AMD's proprietary drivers on your system.

Comment: Can you confirm that your mouse cursor was _not_ affected?

Comment: I sure can.  Mouse cursor is not affected by my workaround; it remains at normal brightness.

EDIT: Or do you mean if I was having the same problem (with the screen dim but not the mouse)?  In this case, yes, I was having the same exact issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to install the proprietary driver. But fortunately I have not seen the dimming for a long time. Maybe it is a fixed bug in Xorg.

Answer (score 0):

I reactivated ATI control in 'colour' section of catalyst Control Centre on my Radeon HD 3450 (Dell S2009W) (Win. Vista) graphics card.
Fixed it straight away.